# Unexpected value of System.Type.FullName

Tags: c#, .net, multidimensional-array, typeof, gettype

I recently needed to build C# specific name (which must always include global:: specifier) for an arbitrary type and have come accross following issue:

```
// 1 - value: System.String[,,,][,,][,]
string unexpectedFullName = typeof( string[,][,,][,,,] ).FullName;      

// 2 - value: System.String[,][,,][,,,]
string expectedFullName = Type.GetType( "System.String[,][,,][,,,]" ).FullName;
```

I was expecting that returned value would be same in both cases. However, for some reason the array related part of the value seems to be reversed (case 1). Is this reversal expected behavior?

Comment: I've come across this before; it seems that while in C# you declare array indices/dimensions in the order in which you read, reflection returns a type name that matches its logical structure. And a (C#) `string[,][,,][,,,]` is, after all, a value of type `string`, thereof a 4-dimensional array (i.e. `string[,,,]`), thereof a 3-dimensional array (i.e. `string[,,,][,,]`) and thereof a 2-dimensional array (i.e. `string[,,,][,,][,]`).

Comment: Everything he said ^^^^. The c# syntax ([explained in depth here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/17/arrays-of-arrays.aspx)) is not required to match the reflection naming convention. So if you are dealing with reflection: use the reflection naming. In other news, nested types are not `Outer.Inner`  but `Outer+Inner` instead, and generics aren't `Foo<,,>` but `Foo\`3` instead.

Comment: I am generating code based on some input types so I will definitely need to reverse information on indices/dimensions provided via System.Type instance.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Could one of you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @MarcGravell: Could one of you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @RestWing I'll let O.R.Mapper take that; but for info, you might also want to look at `someType.MakeArrayType()`

Comment: @MarcGravell: I already have different set of input types, some of them might the array, generic, combination of array and generic and non-generic types. Anyway, thanks for providing additional info.

Comment: @RestWing: Done. I tried to compile the most relevant information from both Marc's and my comments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While the value returned by [`Type.FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname.aspx) and the C# type identifier sometimes happen to be the same, this is not guaranteed. Keep in mind that `Type.FullName` returns the same value regardless of what CLI language it is called from, be it C#, VB.NET, Oxygene or anything else.

For multidimensional and jagged arrays, C# syntax lists the indices in the order they are written later on, while reflection syntax returns something that matches the logical structure of the array. And a (C#) `string[,][,,][,,,]` is, after all, a value of type `string`, thereof a 4-dimensional array (i.e. `string[,,,]`), thereof a 3-dimensional array (i.e. `string[,,,][,,]`) and thereof a 2-dimensional array (i.e. `string[,,,][,,][,]`).

Rather than relying on the reflection syntax name returned by `FullName`, you might want to examine the properties of the `Type` class when analyzing types. Information such as the [number of dimensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getarrayrank.aspx) or the [generic arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) can be retrieved from there.

When constructing types, you can also use methods such as [`MakeArrayType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0ykk2sw.aspx) or [`MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) to create complex types at runtime without constructing a string that contains the ingredients for the new types.

*Some of the contents of this answer was pointed out by [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) - thank you!*

Answer (score 2):

Note: This doesn't directly address your question

> Is this reversal expected behavior?

but I feel it *adds* to it.

---

You can use [`GenerateCodeFromExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.generatecodefromexpression) to return a string which could be used to generate the code to generate the type for you, for instance using this code (modified from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16466858/1364007) by [hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd)):

```
/// <summary>
/// <para>Returns a readable name for this type.</para>
/// <para>e.g. for type = typeof(IEnumerable&lt;IComparable&lt;int&gt;&gt;),</para>
/// <para>type.FriendlyName() returns System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable&lt;System.IComparable&lt;int&gt;&gt;</para>
/// <para>type.Name returns IEnumerable`1</para>
/// <para>type.FullName() returns System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.IComparable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]</para>
/// </summary>
public static string FriendlyName(this Type type)
{
    string result;

    using ( var codeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#") )
    {
        var typeReferenceExpression = new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(new CodeTypeReference(type));
        using ( var writer = new StringWriter() )
        {
            codeDomProvider.GenerateCodeFromExpression(typeReferenceExpression, writer, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
            result = writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

By letting [`codeDomProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider) handle the string representation, **you can be sure** that what's generated will match how you'd define the Type.

**Results with [`FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname):**

```
// returns "System.String[,,,][,,][,]"
typeof(string[,][, ,][, , ,]).FullName; 

// returns "System.String[,][,,][,,,]"
typeof(string[, , ,][, ,][,]).FullName;

// returns "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"
typeof(List<int>).FullName;
```

**Results with `FriendlyName`**

```
// returns "string[,][,,][,,,]"
typeof(string[,][, ,][, , ,]).FriendlyName(); 

// returns "string[,,,][,,][,]"
typeof(string[, , ,][, ,][,]).FriendlyName(); 

// returns "System.Collections.Generic.List<int>"
typeof(List<int>).FriendlyName();
```