# How to display the type of a custom class?

Tags: c#, generic-list

I have created a custom generic list classes called `MyGenList<T>`. I have overriden the `ToString()` method, so that if the list is empty just the type of the object is displayed.

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        if (this.count == 0)
        {
            return this.GetType().ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(elements[i]);
                sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

If I have an empty char list, I want to have `GenericClasses.MyGenList<char>` displayed. However, currently the console displays `GenericClasses.MyGenList1[System.Char]`. Can you please point me to my mistake?

Comment: In case you want to see not this value, why are you not hardcoding it? 
The type is GenericClasses.MyGenList1[System.Char].

Comment: No, the runtime type is that, the designtime type is MyGenList<T>, where T is anything. OP wants to display the type as C# does in code syntax.

Comment: What should be displayed for `MyGenList<List<int>>()` or `MyGenList<Dictionary<int,string>>`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    if (this.count == 0)
    {
        Type t = this.GetType();

        if (t.IsGenericType)
        {
            Type g = t.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

            return g.Name.Remove(g.Name.IndexOf('`')) + "<" + typeof(T).Name + ">";
        }

        return t.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(elements[i]);
            sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought there must be an automatic way without string manipulation, but I guess I was wrong. Your solution works.

Answer (score 1):

`GenericClasses.MyGenList<char>` is the way you see it in code, `GenericClasses.MyGenList1[System.Char]` however is the internal representation.

You could overload the `ToString()` method on your class to display it the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to replace the special ` character and shorten the type names to their C# equivalents.

The following code is copied from another answer here: [Get user-friendly name for generic type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466380/get-user-friendly-name-for-generic-type-in-c-sharp)

```
public static string GetFriendlyName(this Type type)
{
    if (type == typeof(int))
        return "int";
    else if (type == typeof(short))
        return "short";
    else if (type == typeof(byte))
        return "byte";
    else if (type == typeof(bool))
        return "bool";
    else if (type == typeof(long))
        return "long";
    else if (type == typeof(float))
        return "float";
    else if (type == typeof(double))
        return "double";
    else if (type == typeof(decimal))
        return "decimal";
    else if (type == typeof(string))
        return "string";
    else if (type.IsGenericType)
        return type.Name.Split('`')[0] + "<" + string.Join(", ", type.GetGenericArguments().Select(x => GetFriendlyName(x))) + ">";
    else
        return type.Name;
}
```

It's an extension method so it must be placed into a static class, probably called `TypeExt`.

You call it like this (based on your code):

```
return this.GetType().GetFriendlyName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    if (this.count == 0)
    {
        var type = this.GetType().ToString();
        var matches = Regex.Matches(type,
                @"([a-zA-Z0-9`]*\.{1}[a-zA-Z0-9`]*)*")
                .Cast<Match>();
        foreach (Match match in matches.Where(m => m.Value != ""))
        {
            var currentType = Type.GetType(match.Value) 
                ?? Type.GetType(match.Value + "<>");
            type = type.Replace(match.Value, currentType.Name);
        }
        type = type.Replace("`", "");
        return type;
    }
    else
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(this[i]);
            sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Test it for:

```
var list = new MyGenList<Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int, List<DateTime>>>>();
Console.WriteLine(list.ToString());
```