# Convert Type to Its C# Representation

Tags: c#, .net, types

**EDIT**: I want to convert [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) variable to its c# representation.

I recently wanted to use the Type.FullName property to create c# scripts automatically but when I tried to use Type.FullName it returns plus (+) sign instead dot (.).

Here is an example.

```cs
class Outer
{

    class Inner
    {
    }

}
```

Now if you want to access `Inner` class you should do `Outer.Inner` for accessing the `Inner` class.

Type.FullName outputs:

```cs
Outer+Inner
```

While it uses a dot for namespaces.

I know I can fix it by doing a simple Replace call, but it is not the only problem because of the Type.FullName products more unexcepted character and I want to fix them all.

So now, how can I convert the syntax of Type.FullName to C# Syntax?

Here is an example of an illegal syntax of Type.FullName:

```cs
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

While it should be:

```cs
System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>
```

See more examples in MSDN documentation.

[**Try it Online**](https://ideone.com/TDSVbR)

[**Type.FullName Property - MSDN Documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What other unexpected characters are there?

Comment: There are many of them, here is an example: `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]`, the [, numbers and assignments, all of them are illegal syntax. While it should be `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>` and nothing more.

Comment: @MikeDebela My question is different from that. I am looking for a solution to display Type as a string in c# syntax.

Comment: I think you still need all "unexpected" characters. If you want to create a scripts like T4 scripts, you need to know where to get Generic.List, as it can be defined in a few dlls

Comment: So, what you are trying to archive finally?

Comment: I want to convert Type variable to its c# representation.

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] is c# representation = dll and namespace

Comment: @zxxc It is CLR representation. I need the C# representation, and the C# representation for the Generic List is: `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>`.

Comment: I think you can use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466380/get-user-friendly-name-for-generic-type-in-c-sharp#answer-16466858

Comment: @MikeDebela Yes, this is my answer, thanks for sharing.