# Primitive alias for a reflected C# datatype

Tags: c#

In C#, the reflected `Type` object for `int` contains `Int32` for a `Name`. Similarly, `typeof(byte).Name` would be "Byte", etc. Short of introducing an explicit check for all known primitive types, is there a way to retrieve a friendly name (e. g. `int`) from the said `Type` object?

Comment: This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466380/get-user-friendly-name-for-generic-type-in-c-sharp/34001032

Comment: Effectively, "yes, but it's not worth it". :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362884/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-types-alias-through-reflection