# Why does typeof(string[][,]).Name return String[,][]

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types

I hope there is a reason that I simply don't know yet. Why does `typeof(string[][,])` return `String[,][]` as name?

Comment: if you try to do this `typeof(string[][][,][])` it return `typeof(string[][,][][])`, it reverse the order

Comment: "The c# syntax is not required to match the reflection naming convention." (as taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720579/unexpected-value-of-system-type-fullname)